# remove styleurls in "angular2" component

Tags: angular, sass, angular2-template, webpack-style-loader

Can anyone help me to add styles using webpack configuration> I searched in many places, but didn't get proper answer .

---

I need it using sass loading.

I am new to angular2 and webpack too

Please help me?

Comment: If you want to use sass then just download sass loader and configure your webpack to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
styles: [require('pathToCss/function.component.scss')]
```

also , in vendor.ts :

```
import './assets/css/style.scss';
```

Comment: this link could also be usefull : https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-4-and-Sass-(and-jQuery)

Comment: cant we make it without importing styles in component files

Comment: you can import it in vendor.ts

Comment: if possible, could you please create a github repo for that,bcz im new to angular2 and webpack, I don't want to add any styles related (imports/code) in .ts files

Comment: well, the only way i see to do that is a <link> in index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use only styles and require your stylesheet with webpack `styles:[require ('yourStyleSheet')]`

> NOTE:- due to an issue you have to use toString on required style

```
styles: [require("./app.styles.css").toString()]
```

[Here is my github repo which use the same](https://github.com/jorawarsingh/angular2-webpack-seed)
Note:- if you have used required you do not need to import it as the other answer mentioned because webpack will bundle it for you.

Comment: I dind't found any  styles:[require ('yourStyleSheet')] in ur code

Comment: https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts